# Bootstrap 3 nested collapsible elements with shown and hidden events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap collapse to create 3rd menu level. I'm adding `panel-active` class to the parent to change `more` to `less` in CSS. The problem is that when I'm opening `Item 2.1`, `panel-active` class is added to the `#test3` (which is good) AND `#test2` (which is bad). It seems like Bootstrap `shown.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse` events are firing twice when I'm opening/hiding `Item 2.1` and I don't know why it's happening.

To reproduce the problem try to hide `Item 2.1`.

```js
$('.panel-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('panel-active');
});

$('.panel-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('panel-active');
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.list-group-item.panel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sidebar-submenu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-submenu a {
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  display: block;
}
.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu a {
  padding-left: 60px !important;
}
.list-group a[data-toggle] {
  position: relative;
}
.list-group-item > a[data-toggle]:after,
.sidebar-submenu-item > a[data-toggle]:after
{
  content: 'more';
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 6px;
  color: #333;
  z-index: 438
}
.panel-active > a[data-toggle]:after {
  content: 'less'
 }
.list-group .list-group-item a {
  padding: 13px 12px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.list-group .list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="list-group" id="sidebar-menu">

        <li class="list-group-item panel panel-default">
          <a href="#test1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-menu" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw icon-left"></i>Item 1</a>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="test1">
            <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 1.1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 1.2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 1.3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item panel panel-default">
          <a href="#test2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-menu" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw icon-left"></i>Item 2</a>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="test2">
            <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item">
                <a href="#test3" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed">Item 2.1</a>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="test3">
                  <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
                    <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.1.2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.1.3</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are clicking on a child, you are also clicking on the parent element too so both events for both the parent and the child both fire. To only fire the child event and stop it propogating up the dom tree, add `e.stopPropagation()` as below.

```js
$('.panel-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().addClass('panel-active');
});

$('.panel-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().removeClass('panel-active');
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.list-group-item.panel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sidebar-submenu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-submenu a {
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  display: block;
}
.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-submenu a {
  padding-left: 60px !important;
}
.list-group a[data-toggle] {
  position: relative;
}
.list-group-item > a[data-toggle]:after,
.sidebar-submenu-item > a[data-toggle]:after
{
  content: 'more';
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 6px;
  color: #333;
  z-index: 438
}
.panel-active > a[data-toggle]:after {
  content: 'less'
 }
.list-group .list-group-item a {
  padding: 13px 12px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.list-group .list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="list-group" id="sidebar-menu">

        <li class="list-group-item panel panel-default">
          <a href="#test1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-menu" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw icon-left"></i>Item 1</a>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="test1">
            <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 1.1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 1.2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 1.3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item panel panel-default">
          <a href="#test2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-menu" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw icon-left"></i>Item 2</a>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="test2">
            <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item">
                <a href="#test3" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed">Item 2.1</a>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="test3">
                  <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
                    <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.1.2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.1.3</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-submenu-item"><a href="#">Item 2.3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So fast :) Great, I will test it and accept your answer after.

Comment: Works great, I will give you a bounty in 23 hours :)